How to have tikzpicture environment properly formatted in align environment
I've tried to figure out how to use the the tikzpicture environment within an align environment, and the closest thing to an answer I found is here: use of tikzpicture matrix in align or gather environment. This doesn't answer my question, however, because it involves the usage of the tikzlibrary and specifically revolves around matrices.
After researching a bit myself and looking at the code for figure 3.20 in https://tikz.org/examples/chapter-03-drawing-positioning-and-aligning-nodes/ I managed to make the following:

Here's the MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x_1 = \frac{
\tikz[baseline=(label.base)] \node[circle, draw=red, text=blue, inner sep=1pt, very thick](label){0};
^2-2}{\tikz[baseline=(label.base)] \node[circle, draw=red, text=blue, inner sep=1pt, very thick](label){0};
^2-2\cdot \tikz[baseline=(label.base)] \node[circle, draw=red, text=blue, inner sep=1pt, very thick](label){0};
}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rcirc/.style={circle, draw=red, text=blue, very thick, inner sep=1pt}, baseline=(label.base)]
    \(x_1 = \frac{\tikz \node[rcirc](label){0};^2-2}{\tikz \node[rcirc](label){0};^2-2\cdot \tikz \node[rcirc](label){0};}\)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{align*}

\end{document}

As you can see, it works perfectly fine when manually inserting all of the commands. Only when I try to make the process "automatic" by utilizing the tikzpicture environment do I encounter trouble with the formatting. Is it possible to fix it so that I can get the same results with tikzpicture as without it? Simple solutions would be preferred since I'm still relatively new to LaTeX and trying to build up a strong foundation based on simplicity first and then expanding, but if no other alternative is available except for a complex solution, so be it.
Edit: It has come to my attention that nesting is basically unsupported for tikzpicture (see comments for further details) and thus a slight modification to my original question would be how to create a tikzpicture environment that works like the align environment for math and formats it properly like the first example I provided?

For one thing, you're nesting tikzpictures. If you want to keep it simple, this is the absolute opposite. Basically, nesting is unsupported. If you really understand what you're doing and either know what you're doing is safe or can write code to compensate, you can get it to work in a limited range of cases. But, even then, it should be an absolute last resort and you should be prepared for breakage. In what sense is the second version more 'automatic' than the first and what bothers you about the result? (That the layout of the maths is wrong, because you're laying it out manually?)

I would use the tikzmark library in a case like this.

In the second one, can define a style which encompasses all of the specifications, hence I can just insert that shortcut to each node instead of writing all of the specifications out each time. This is more convenient for me.
I should mention that I'm an absolute noob at LaTeX, and thus I have no idea what's dangerous to do and what not. I just follow my intuition of what's the easiest structure to follow and try to execute it searching for information on the commands. I had no idea nesting is suboptimal. It usually works for me with other environments, so I thought it'd be the same here.

With that being said, I've now got a new question given the information you provided me with: How can you construct a tikzpicture environment which imitates the formatting of an align environment and is optimal for math?

I wouldn't. I would keep the math formatting as standard and integrate the drawing stuff. I'd have overlaid it, but egreg's solution is probably better (because egreg's solutions are almost always better). It depends if you want the circles to affect the spacing of the elements or not.

Yeah, egreg's ability to break down what seems like a complex operation into a simple solution is amazing and always greatly appreciated. With that being said, however, I personally think that there may also be some drawbacks with the simple solutions such as limited customizability. Therefore, even if you have a more complex solution, but it allows for finer control or something additional, I wouldn't mind you sharing it at all - Perhaps I'll one day come back to it when I'm advanced enough to understand it and actually be able to use it in a practical problem! :)

I'd define a specific command:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}

\newcommand{\circlednumber}[1]{%
  {\tikz[baseline=(label.base)] \node[circlednumber](label){#1};}%
}
\tikzset{
  circlednumber/.style={circle, draw=red, text=blue, inner sep=1pt, very thick},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
x_1 &= \frac{\circlednumber{0}^2-2}{\circlednumber{0}^2-2\circlednumber{0}}
\\
x_2 &= \frac{\circlednumber{1}^2-2}{\circlednumber{1}^2-2\circlednumber{1}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}

As a general rule, never use align for single equations.


Oh wow, I never thought of doing it through creating a macro. It seems like these macros are a really powerful tool which would be worthwhile to learn - Thanks!
Also, I usually use the equation environment for a single line or equation with a split environment nested inside of it for multiple lines, but I thought I'd use align for simplicity here. I'm curious to know why align is suboptimal for single line equations if you don't mind explaining it, however:)

@Atex align always uses \abovedisplayskip vertical space above it, whereas equation can use \abovedisplayshortskip if appropriate.

Gooot it, tysm for ur help! It's really nice to see that you always somehow manage to find the simplest and most intuitive solutions for people's questions in here - It helps on really making new people like me understand what's actually going on instead of just getting lost in the code and copy pasting it! Do you know any good resources for learning the power of macros? Or just refer to the best place for getting started on them?

I know it has been a while, but I've learned a bit more about tikz now. From what I could read here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles, it seems like \tikzset is generally a newer command which is more versatile, but wouldn't \tikzstyle be just as convenient of a solution as the one you provided to my problem from back then, because we were only interested in defining a new style to use in a new command?

@Atex \tikzstyle has been deprecated for several years. Doing stylename/.style=<settings> inside \tikzset is the preferred method.
